# How to upload two images (i.e Profile and cover) on single submit using mongoose, express, Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
exports.postAddProject = (req, res, next) =>  {
    /*const {logo} = req.files */
    const {cover, profile} = req.files
    const uploadPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/uploads/logo', logo.name)
    logo.mv(uploadPath, (error) => {
        Admin.create({
            ...req.body,
            logo: `/uploads/logo/${ logo.name }`,
        }, (error, admin) => {
            if(error) {**strong text**
                return res.redirect('/')
            }
            console.log('Added to database')
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    })
}
```

In above code cover and profile are two images. `const {cover, profile} = req.files` code below this is fully functional for single image but how can i upload two image with this same controller?